# Confusion over the logic of "This condition will always return 'false' since the types '"a"' and '"b"' have no overlap."

Tags: javascript, typescript, if-statement, logic

I just started learning TypeScript, and I'm currently reading the handbook. One of the points it makes it that TypeScript catches logic errors, and it gives this example:

```js
const value = Math.random() < 0.5 ? "a" : "b";
if (value !== "a") {
  // ...
} else if (value === "b") {
  // This condition will always return 'false' since 
  // the types '"a"' and '"b"' have no overlap.
  // Oops, unreachable
}
```

Probably there's just something I'm not seeing straight, but I can't get why this should throw an error. Here's how I see it:

- `value` can be either `a` or `b`
- The first if statement checks to see if `value` isn't `a`
- The else-if statement checks if the value *is* `b`, which it would always be if it wasn't `a` (if `value` is not `a`; it's `b`)

So why does it say `value === "b"` will always return `false`? Obviously this doesn't work the way I'm looking at it; it seems like there's something I'm missing. Also I'm not totally sure what `overlap` in `'"a"' and '"b"' have no overlap` means, so if someone could help me understand these, it'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `else` Basically, there is never a situation where `value === "a"` (which it would have to be if `value !== "a"` returned false) AND `value === "b"` (which it would have to be if `value === "b"` returned true). The `else` branch is only read if the condition in the first `if` returns false (falsy in JavaScript's case).

Comment: @HereticMonkey - shucks, how did I not see that ‍♂️...obviously `value !== "a"` is the same as `value === "b"` in this case... thanks for clearing this up though.

Comment: @blankpage how about that ?

const value = Math.random() < 0.5 ? "a" : "b";
if (value !== "a") {

} else if (value !== "b") {
    
}
1)The first if statement checks to see if the value isn't a
2)The second if-else statement checks to see if the value isn't b

if you could explained the logic error I  would appreciate

Comment: @CihatŞaman, `value` can either be "a" or "b", depending on `Math.random()`. So if `value` is not "a", then it *has* to be "b". For the 1st if-statement to be called, i.e., if `value` is not "a", then it must be "b". So whenever `value` is "b", the 1st `if` is evaluated. This means that when `value` reaches the 2nd statement, it **cannot be "b"**, because then the 1st statement would've be called. Thus it must be "a", so the 2nd statement will always evaluate to true, if it is reached. So, there's no point of having an `else-if` in this case; just replace it with an `else`, and it should work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/67196091

Comment: The else statement wont be executed because if value is `b`(value !== 'a') the first statement will be true and the else wont be executed.