# Typescript says: "types '"a"' and '"b"' have no overlap". What does it mean?

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
const value = Math.random() < 0.5 ? "a" : "b";
if (value !== "a") {
  // ...
} else if (value === "b") {
This condition will always return 'false' since the types '"a"' and '"b"' have no overlap.

  // Oops, unreachable
}
```

Found this code in a tutorial. I want to understand the meaning of this error: `"types '"a"' and '"b"' have no overlap."`

What are they talking about?

Comment: If the value is "b" won't that get captured in the first if? Meaning the second condition can never be hit?

Comment: Since value can *only* be `a` or `b`, `value !== "a"` implies `value === "b"`, therefore the `else if` clause *cannot* be true since if `value === "b"` the if branch will be taken.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In TypeScript `"a"` is [a literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types). It is a type that has exactly one value, which is `"a"`. Equivalently for `"b"`.

Due to the way you initialize `value` TypeScript considers the type of `value` to be `"a" | "b"` (a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) that basically means the value must be either of type `"a"` or of type `"b"`.

If the type (and therefore also the value) of `value` is *not* `"a"` then the block of the first if will be executed.

That means that the condition of the `else if` will definitely operate on a value of type (and value) `"a"`. Now you are comparing a value of type `"a"` with a value of type `"b"`.

But no value in TypeScript can be of type `"a"` and of type `"b"` at the same time, since **the types have no overlap** (which is just another way of saying that no value can be of both types at the same time).

In other words: TypeScript figured out that `value` can't be `"b"` at that point and therefore that second block after the `else if` will never be executed.

As a counter example of types with overlap, consider `string` and `"a"`. The value `"a"` is obviously of type `string`. It is *also* of type `"a"` (by definition). That means that the types `string` and `"a"` *have some overlap*.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, `value` can only be the string `'a'` or `'b'`, so:

```js
if (value !== 'a') {
  // here value can ONLY be 'b'
} else {
  // here value can ONLY be 'a'
}
```

So in this case, the condition `else if (value === 'b')` can't be reached and TypeScript prevent you and specify that `'a' !== 'b'`.